# Is it bad practice to search for strings in exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am trying to write a context manager to handle exceptions, and the same exception can come up in different functions:

`ValueError: Foo is not Bar`

`ValueError: Img is not X`

etc.

So I have been catching exceptions by parsing the strings of exceptions.

Is this frowned upon?

Comment: I would come up with a new type for each error, or at least use a bit more structure than a string. Parsing error strings sounds very error prone to me.

Comment: @AlexHart I think OP is not the one controlling how the errors are thrown, so he's trying to handle the different exceptions this way.

Answer (score 1):

In the unittest for `argparse`, `test_argparse.py` there are tests like:

```
    with self.assertRaises(ArgumentParserError) as cm:
        parser.parse_args(['-V'])
    self.assertEqual('XXX 3.7\n', cm.exception.stdout)
```

or even more elaborate:

```
    with self.assertRaises(ArgumentParserError) as cm:
        parser.parse_args([])
    msg = str(cm.exception)
    self.assertRegex(msg, 'req_pos')
    self.assertNotIn(msg, 'optional_positional')
```

Most of the tests just check for a specific exception subclass.  But some do check the exception message.  So unittesting does have tools for checking the messages.

But defining a few exception subclasses for the module is a good idea.  They don't need any special methods or content.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use `unittest` methods in production code?